# Interface hybrid inheritance does not throw error in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, hybrid

I have three interfaces A, B and C and one class D. B and C extend A and D implements B and C. Interface A has a default method called "does". I was expecting to have a compile-time error or run-time error, however, the program was executed without error.
Both B and C inherit from A. Shouldn't the compiler be confused as to which inherited method be called on D since D inherits two default methods one from C and one from B.
All of the three interfaces and the class are defined in separate files. I have placed the code sequentially in the code area below for demonstration.

```
public interface A {

    default public void does(){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

public interface B extends A {
}

public interface C extends A {
}

public class D implements B, C {    
}

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new D().does();
    }

}
```

Comment: *D inherits two default methods one from C and one from B.* No, it inherits the same default method from both.

Comment: No, the compiler will not be confused. There's only one implementation of `does `, which is what will be used.

Comment: I remember when my teacher told us in the class hybrid inhertance is not supported in java because of D would inherit two methods and the compiler would be confused. now I am confused as to why he said that.

Comment: He means that in Java we cannot inherit from multiple classes.

But it's not the point in case of interfaces where no implementation provided, only signature. Your class can implement as many interfaces as you want.

And if 2 interfaces define the method with the same signature, the class that implements both of them is supposed to provide the implementation for this method.

Comment: @star67 oh ok i get this now. but you said "if 2 interfaces define the method with the same signature, the class that implements both of them is supposed to provide the implementation for this method". why can't we do the same thing with classes. if 2 classes define the method with the same signature, the class that implements both of them would provide an implementation. but the compiler throws an error in case of classes. is there a reason why interfaces are permitted to do this and classes not allowed?

Comment: This is what is known as method shadowing, plus in Java 1.8 and up that method defined is implicitly static